# Populating Lists or Vectors dynamically

Tags: python, numpy

Using Python 3.4 and numpy

Hey all, Spent about an hour looking, and not sure if this is possible.

I am creating a dynamic model with 1000 iterations. I can write a transition function from state 1 to state 2, state 2 to state 3, etc.

After I have the 1000 iteration I am using np.arange to find an initial value of some of my variables that will reach convergence by the 1000th iteration, given the exogenous variables.

I was wondering if there is a way to create all 1000 iterations quickly, ie write some code that looks like this:

```
for y_0 in np.arange(0.0001, 2, 0.0001):
    x_0 = 2
    z_0 = 1
    # something # (y_i+1 = x_i + y_i, 1000)
    # something # (x_i+1 = z_i + y_i, 1000)
if abs(y_1000 - y_999) < 1:
    print(y_0, y_1 ... y_1000)
    break
else: 
    print('fail')
```

That returns something like this:

```
y_1 = x_0 + y_0
x_1 = z_0 + y_0
...
y_1000 = x_999 + y_999
x_1000 = z_999 + y_999
```

Does that make sense? Is there a function that could help me?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

So, thinking about it, I guess there are two ways to accomplish what I want, but I'm not sure if either are possible.

The first is to create code, by pasting my initial transition function in a way that updated the last digit(s). So I could generate

```
y_i+1 = x_i + y_i
x_i+1 = z_i + y_i
```

A thousand times (hopefully in an automated fashion), resulting in

```
 y_1 = x_0 + y_0
 x_1 = z_0 + y_0
 y_2 = x_1 + y_1
 x_2 = z_1 + y_1
 ...
 y_1000 = x_999 + y_999
 x_1000 = z_999 + y_999
```

The second would be a function that iterates the transition functions and returns the 1000 values of y when it finds a value of y_0 that satisfies abs(y_1000 - y_999) < 1.

My actual functions are much more complex, over 20 lines long, so I don't want to post them.

Edit2:

So here is what I have so far, thanks to your help. However, here is the output I am getting:

> Convergence reached
>   [ 1.5        1.6473105  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.

and so on for a lot of zeros. This confuses me, as the third step in my system is non zero if I just do out the math. It seems like the system is just running for two periods, then reverting to zero (not populating the array) for the remaining periods and then patting itself on the back for converging.

Again, thank you very much for any advice you have.

EDIT: Figured it out. I needed to run the iteration before I make the code break when the 99th converges

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the reply. I'll update the original post,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Numpy arrays indexing to store the data of your dynamic model,

```
import numpy as np

dtype = 'float128'
abs_tolerance = 1.0

y = np.arange(0.001, 2, 0.02).astype(dtype)
N = y.shape[0]

x = np.zeros(N, dtype=dtype)
z = np.zeros(N, dtype=dtype)
x[0] = 2
z[0] = 1  # initialize the first step

for idx in range(1, N):
    y[idx] = x[idx-1] + y[idx-1]
    x[idx] = z[idx-1] + y[idx-1]
    if np.abs(y[idx] - y[idx-1]) < abs_tolerance:
        print('Convergence reached')
        break

else:
    print('Convergence failed, exiting after {} steps'.format(idx))

x = np.asarray(x)
z = np.asarray(z)
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

Note, as it is now, the relation between `x`, `y` and `z` doesn't make much sens and it is going to overflow quickly (hence the use of 128bit floats).

Also if you can formulate your problem in a [state-space representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation), you should rather use [`scipy.signal.lti`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) which is designed for such problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for a very helpful answer. If I could trouble you a little more, I am updating the original post.